# SQL Query to comparing the minutes in SQL 2008 R2 server

Tags: sql

What am trying to do is, I have table with Date field. Date field has entry in datetime format. Using that i have to display todays records after 5PM. Can anyone help me on this to get this query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 Pm ?
Try this:

```
select *From Table where DATEPART(hh,yourdatefield)>=17 and and convert(date,yourdatefield,103)='2014-04-03'
```

this will the the records after 5pm .

Comment: I really thankful for you dear. Its worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select *
FROM tablename
WHERE datefield < '1/1/2014 17:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
where 
CONVERT(date,Datefield) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) and
CONVERT(time,Datefield) > convert(time,'17:00')
```